# Some messages shows when vim startup

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

When I try to start or `source` neovim/vim/vi, I'll get follow messages.

```
syntax_on             #1
did_load_filetypes    #1
ft_ignore_pat          \.\(Z\|gz\|bz2\|zip\|tgz\)$
b:changedtick         #1
v:beval_winid         #0
v:version             #800
v:t_list              #3
v:beval_winnr         #0
v:errors              []
v:lnum                #0
v:hlsearch            #1
v:t_channel           #9
v:oldfiles            [
v:dying               #0
v:windowid            #0
v:mouse_winid         #0
v:lang                 C.UTF-8
v:t_none              #7
v:count               #0
v:progpath             /usr/bin/vim.basic
v:true                 v:true
v:t_string            #1
v:none                 v:none
v:progname             vi
v:t_bool              #6
v:t_number            #0
v:vim_did_enter       #0
v:cmdbang             #0
v:foldlevel           #0
v:t_func              #2
v:ctype                C.UTF-8
v:t_job               #8
v:prevcount           #0
v:register             "
v:mouse_win           #0
v:count1              #0
v:foldstart           #0
v:foldend             #0
v:profiling           #0
v:t_float             #5
v:null                 v:null
v:beval_col           #0
v:beval_lnum          #0
v:mouse_lnum          #0
v:completed_item      {}
v:t_dict              #4
v:false                v:false
v:beval_bufnr         #0
v:shell_error         #0
v:testing             #0
v:lc_time              C.UTF-8
v:searchforward       #1
v:event               {}
v:mouse_col           #0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I don't know what's happend. I was tried to setup some vim key map befor I saw those messages first.
After that, I tried to off all plugin, and it's dosen`t work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a line in your `.vimrc` / `.config/nvim/init.vim`, or some file included by them, that just says `let`. Maybe you got distracted in the middle of writing something else?